# What are the differences between "declarative" and "imperative" frameworks in UI development?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, declarative, imperative

I've been trying to understand the differences between declarative and imperative frameworks in the context of UI development. However, despite my research, I'm still finding it hard to grasp these concepts clearly.

Could someone explain the key differences between these two types of frameworks? Please include illustrative examples of both declarative and imperative frameworks and how the coding approach or style might differ between them. Any analogy or simple explanation to make these concepts more understandable would be greatly appreciated.